# Differential equation with $z=x^2+y^2$ transform

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> **Task:** Does the exact differential equation
>   $$
> x\,dx+y\,dy+x\,dy-y\,dx=0
> $$
>   have an integrating factor of the form  $α=α(z)$, $z=x^2+y^2$.

In the provided solution there is a step where in the original equation (for the integrating factor)
$$\frac{\partial{\ln\alpha(x,y)}}{\partial y}  M - \frac{\partial{\ln\alpha(x,y)}}{\partial x}  N = \frac{\partial N }{ \partial x} - \frac{\partial M}{ \partial y}$$

we choose
$z = x^2 + y^2$
and say $\alpha = \alpha(z)$

and so original equation takes the form

$$2(My-Nx)\frac{\partial\ln\alpha}{\partial z} = \frac{\partial N }{ \partial x} - \frac{\partial M}{ \partial y}$$

It says that when we pick the function $\alpha$ as a function of $(x^2+y^2)$ equation comes to this form. I'm trying to understand it and prove it but I couldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Op's question has changed a bit 
$$\frac{\partial\ln\mu}{\partial y}M-\frac{\partial\ln\mu}{\partial x}N=\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}\tag{1.18}$$
$$\frac{\partial\ln\mu}{\partial z}\frac {\partial z}{\partial y}M-\frac{\partial\ln\mu}{\partial z}\frac {\partial z}{\partial x}N=\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}\tag{1.18}$$
$$\frac{\partial\ln\mu}{\partial z}2yM-\frac{\partial\ln\mu}{\partial z}2xN=\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}\tag{1.18}$$
$$2(My-Nx)\frac{\partial\ln\mu}{\partial z}=\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}\tag{1.18}$$

Comment: Thank you so much. I dont know why i couldnt see that. Happens some times.

Comment: @ErayXx yw yeah it happens sometimes...

Answer (score 1):

In transforming to radial coordinates $(x,y)=(r\cos\phi,r\sin\phi)$ you get with a little calculation that
$$
\frac12\,dz=r\,dr=x\,dx+y\,dy
$$
and 
$$
d\phi=\frac{x\,dy-y\,dx}{x^2+y^2}
$$
where you should recognize the components of your expression.